# Complex streaming logic of a LinkedList

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm dealing with a complex bit of logic that I can't get right. I'm trying to reduce a list that contains a list of properties into a one merged object, removing duplicate *keys*.

Say I have a `Config` class with the following elements:

```
private int index;
private String name;
private Map<String, String> properties;
```

This object will be in a linked list of objects, `List<Config>`. If the `Config` object at index 5 has a key/value in `properties` of "version=2", but the `Config` object at index 1 has `properties` that contain "version=1", I need the property in index 5 to win. So I want one final `Config` (I'll worry about the `name` element later) that has merged properties that reflect the latest properties in the stream.

Am I asking for too much in one operation? So far I've come up with something like this, but it doesn't compile:

```
configList.stream()
        .map(it -> it.getProperties())
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> 
            new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(???))))
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: So you want to find the config with the highest version?

Comment: That's exactly what I need! But I need all the other properties too, except those that were duplicated.

Comment: *But I need all the other properties too, except those that were duplicated* this is the part I don't understand. you want to get the highest version `Config`; but merge all *other* Config's `properties` into this highest one?

Comment: If the map `properties` contains key-value pairs where is the version info you are talking about?

Comment: Config 1 may have properties that Config 5 doesn't. So I need the properties from Config 1 in the final list also. But if they have the same property defined, I only want the property from Config 5.

Comment: "version" is one of the entries in `properties` and was just an example. But there will be hundreds of properties in each `Config`.

Comment: So then all properties in one `Config` object has the same version?

Comment: Yes, you could say that!

Comment: In the end you want to have one config where each property comes from the config which had the highest version containing the property. Right?

Comment: Yes LuCio, that is correct.

Comment: My advice would be to not write this using a stream, at least no to start with. Write some static method with a basic but clear functionality and once that works as expected you might consider trying to make a stream out of it.

Comment: What if props that are in previous version are missing in newer?

Comment: Tony, I need the props that were in the previous version as well. I need to accumulate them all into one merged `Config`. But I can't have duplicates.

Comment: Most likely need join operation of properties, then add whatever is missing from the latest

Comment: But how would I tell the join to supersede one value over another, if they were they had the same key?

Comment: Oh, then you are looking for a union or all related properties

Comment: Ok, sure! I don't know how to do that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to get all the properties and merge them into one Map and if there is duplicate, you want to prioritise the property of map with highest index value in config.

This is the solution I came up with.

```
Map<String, String> properties = configList.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Config::getIndex)) //Sort the configs in ascending order by indexes.
                .flatMap(config -> config.properties.entrySet().stream()) //flat map all the properties
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (left, right) -> right)); //collect to a map
```

This `Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (left, right) -> right)` is where the magic happens.

Since we already sorted the configs by index, we will always have the value with higher config index at bottom and all we do is overwrite the existing key when duplicate key occurs.

Comment: Not bad, next step is using names field, which might be used to uniquely identify a config amongst other configs.

Comment: Not bad, next step is using names field, which might be used to uniquely identify a config amongst other configs.

Comment: My bad, I missed the name part all-together. Well I will add the .thenComparing in the answer now.

Comment: I'll be damned, I think that's what I need!! Let me try a few more tests...

Comment: Or wait @Tony I think I am not entirely sure what to do with the name. I think he doesn't want it to be in the comparator but needs to do something else with it.

Comment: Nope, not worried about the name! I'm accepting the answer. Thanks for all your input!!

Comment: @user1660256 glad to help :)

Comment: While this answer is clever and does a good job, I really don't understand how the properties map with the highest version wins against lower versions. What does the index have to do with all this? Besides, sorting is `O(NlogN)`, while getting the max is only `O(N)`, so I think that sorting isn't at all needed.

Comment: It is because if you have configs in index order (2->1->3) and if there is a duplicated key in properties of 2 and 1 but not in the max (3) then the value of properties at index 2 will be overwritten by that of index 1.

Comment: Then, I think you should sort by version property instead of by index.

Comment: But version was just an example key in the map. It can be anything. Also I don’t see how that will work. OP wanted to have highest index properties to overwrite any lower index property key’s value. Can you write an answer to the question with what you mean?